# Ubuntu Install-creating drive: cannot shrink volume beyond the point where any removable files are located

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I am trying to dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 on my computer. I currently have Windows 10 installed and am trying to partition(split) my D drive to create a new drive for Ubuntu. My D drive currently has 100GB of free space. However, in Disk Management, only 4.85GB is showing up as "available shrink space." Therefore, I cannot make a new drive big enough to run Ubuntu on. Is there any way of getting around this? It might be helpful to know windows says "cannot shrink volume beyond the point where any removable files are located."
Best, Kevin

edit: The defragment and optimization tool doesn't help, I pressed "optimized" but nothing changes

Comment: We only answer Ubuntu problems. Yours is with Windows or with Windows tools. Use a gparted live dvd and see if that works. If not we can try to help with that.

Comment: Well . . . the question can be solved with Ubuntu tools, using a live USB/DVD and GParted . . . Someone will address that son

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this isn't Ubuntu related. But, try this.

1. Make an Ubuntu Live USB. Skip this step if you have other Ubuntu installation media handy.
2. Plug in the media and boot into it. (Use F2, F8, F9, F10 or F12 or Esc to get into boot menu if need be)
3. Open Gparted by hitting the Windows key and typing in Gparted.
4. Right click the partition you want to resize (be very careful about which you select).
5. Chose `Resize/Move` from the context menu.
6. Fill out the parameters or simply drag the sliders.
7. Hit apply.
8. Rejoice.

**NOTE: As with any operation relating to your hard disks, please try and make a backup before proceeding.**